# vs2008 website upgraded to vs2013 pulling wrong system.core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have two sites that are vs2008, .net 3.5. I am upgrading them to vs2013, but want to keep them at .net 3.5. I carried out the upgrade and one site runs fine as .net 3.5, but the other one gets this error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Post-policy reference: System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Using fuslog shows the .net 3.5 system.core loading correctly. But immediately afterwards it tries to load system.core 4.0.0.0 with the calling assembly shown as:

```
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
```

I've already checked to make sure every project in the solution is targeting .net 3.5
I can't figure out why the other site works fine - their references are identical.

Comment: did you try to rebuild and/or check the iisexpress settings?

Comment: yes, clean and rebuild produced the same result. I even tried restarting.

Comment: did you open up the properties of the project to make sure that the version of .net that you are wanting to compile, is set to 3.5 and not 4.0 the changing of this will update the .config file..  I would double check that

Comment: Target framework is set to 3.5, and webconfig is still the same as on vs2008

Comment: it looks like the source of this issue is iis express is using a cached copy of my webconfig and not my current one. Where is the iisexpress cached copy located so i can nuke it?